# Can't umount /cdrom

Tags: system-installation

During instalation, right after partitioning, the process is stopped and I get the message:

> "can't umount /cdrom"

From searching the web I noticed this is an old bug from Ubuntu installer, but all the workarounds presume some knowledge of bash and the ability to run a terminal alongside the installer, both of which I lack.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You can alternatively burn the image into an usb dongle. Is this problem recurring?

Comment: Are you installing from live usb? If yes, disable any floppy diskette and any slave in BIOS settings, and try again. Please let me know :)

Comment: To run said terminal you can click "try elementary" then open a terminal, then run the installer.